# Alert gives TypeError: this is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a react app using `create-app` and I am making a form for registration, it has for now only two fields one for email and one for password.

I am making a simple test and I want to show the values I put in as input by using an alert, so like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        email:'',
        password:''
      };
      this.handleEmailChange = this.handleEmailChange.bind(this);
      this.handlePasswordChange = this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleEmailChange(e){
    this.setState({email:e.target.value})
  }
  handlePasswordChange(e){
    this.setState({password:e.target.value})
  }

  signIn(){
    alert('Email address is ' + this.state.email + ' Password is ' + this.state.password);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form className="form-signin">
                <h2 className="form-signin-heading"> Please sign in </h2>
                <label for="inputEmail" className="sr-only"> Email address</label>
                <input type="email" onChange={this.handleEmailChange} id="inputEmail" className="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus />
                <label for="inputPassword" className="sr-only"> Password</label>
                <input type="password" onChange={this.handlePasswordChange} id="inputPassword" className="form-control" placeholder="Password" required />
                <button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"  onClick={this.signIn} type="button"> Sign in </button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

When I run

```
npm start
```

I can see my application on localhost but when I fill in the values and want to see those results I get this error:

```
TypeError: this is undefined

  23 | signIn(){
> 24 |   alert('Email address is ' + this.state.email + ' Password is ' + this.state.password);
  25 | }
```

How can I get this error fixed?

Comment: Conver the alert to console.log, then tell me what it says.

Comment: you have to bind this

Answer (score 5):

You need to bind it in the constructor, like you do with your other functions. In the constructor add:

```
this.signIn= this.signIn.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 2):

Either you bind the function in constructor like this

```
this.signIn= this.signIn.bind(this);
```

or change `signIn()` function to use Arrow function

```
signIn = () => {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the button tag change

```
onClick={this.signIn} to {this.signIn.bind(this)}
```

Or

In the constructor, add

```
this.signIn = this.signIn.bind(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

Error in the above code is binding is missing for signIn function. because in this function you are trying to access the state variables using "this" keyword.
but as you didn't bind the function in the constructor so this scope is missing.
add the below line in constructor
this.signIn=this.signIn.bind(this);
it will work.

you can even try below way of binding 
onClick={this.signIn.bind(this)}
this is not a recommended way of binding.